# Django Admin: filter foreign keys presented in dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys

In my app I have the following model to manage series, seasons and episodes:

```
class Series(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    year = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "series"

class Season(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('number', 'series',)

class Episode(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('number', 'season',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm using Django admin to manage my models: I set the Season as an inline of Series (it looks weird to create seasons by itself outside the series context). Until this point, everything is fine.

As I cannot nest again episodes inside seasons, the episodes need to be created separately. 
However, the episode form contains 2 dropdowns: one to select the season (listing all the existing seasons from all series in the DB), and another one to select the series. 
What I want here is to see only the seasons from the selected series.

Is this achievable or do I really need to select the season from all the existent ones? Is there a common approach to solve this?

Comment: Of course a possible way to do this is to create series, and separately create seasons with inline episodes. I'm just trying to see if django-admin is manageable to this point.

Comment: You will need to use javascript (and probably ajax) to filter update the seasons when a series is selected. There are plenty of questions about this and also some applications to help